# structuring of models in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my rails app I have the following models: users, games and players. A user has many games and a game has many players. So far it is really quite simple but the problem is that in one game the maximum amount of players is 8 and there is a possibility of joining a game after the maximum number of players has been reached but then you are a reserve.

So the question is: Should I have an extra reserve model? And how should all the models be associated with each other?
At the moment I have solved it by adding a reserve attribute to the player model and when the maximum amount is reached the reserve attribute is turned to 1 instead of 0. This solution feels a little clumsy and needs a lot of code. I was wondering if anyone has done something similar and had a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to Game model.

```
has_many :players

def is_reserved
 self.players.count >= 8 ? true : false
end
```

Then place a condition where you are adding the players to game. I am assuming that you have the @game object.

```
unless @game.is_reserved
  // add players
else
 // show the warning messaage or do nothing
end
```

Hope it will work for you.